# Android Content Provider without SQL

Tags: android

my android application is handling a large database of bus passage time and we would like to allow others application to be able to display certains bus passage time. We would like to use a content provider to do that. Most example seems to be about using an SQL database, but... we use some custom text file. I was wondering what would be the best way to do that. I was thinking I could use a Content Provider and implement the Cursor interface on a custom object that I would manually fill with my text data. Would this be possible ? Anyone have a better idea (excluding changing to SQL lite of course) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would this be possible ?

Sure. `ConetntProvider` is, in effect, a facade, not dictating all that much about the internal implementation.

The key will be documentation. If you are not using SQLite as a data store, you most likely will not be supporting full `WHERE` clauses for `query()` and such. Hence, you need to make sure that whatever you do support for `WHERE` clauses, available columns, and the like, you document it well, so developers integrating with your content provider know how to do it. Otherwise, they may make faulty assumptions.

Comment: Even if I hack around with URI, how can I dodge Cursor ? (using new DB, Realm)

Comment: @Dexter: You cannot "dodge Cursor". Realm is not designed to be put behind a `ContentProvider`. You would have to convert Realm results into a `MatrixCursor` or some other `Cursor` implementation.

Comment: My main motive is to use CursorLoader and sync adapters. Should i implement some form of cursor or should I skip content provider totally and make custom code. I know its a vauge qstn, but what would you do in my situation. My syncing needs are pretty basic.

Comment: @Dexter: I have not played with a sync adapter yet and so do not know how best to tie sync adapters to Realm -- sorry!

Comment: Just linking "You would have to convert Realm results into a MatrixCursor" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966881/realm-share-database-between-apps

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have any example or url which shows how to create content provider without SQL or create content provider with like mysql,oracle,h2 etc database?

Comment: @nitishpatel: "do you have any example or url which shows how to create content provider without SQL" -- see [`FileProvider`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java). "create content provider with like mysql,oracle,h2 etc database?" -- neither MySQL nor Oracle run on Android. `ContentProvider` is not designed for querying remote data sources live.